# How to store weather data with JPA

Tags: file, jpa, weather

The project is required to store large weather data (http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/igra/)
into file system with JPA. I mean disk files.

How to store those data. For example, how to organize the files? So that we can retrieve those files for retrieving.

Comment: I can't see the relation between JPA (Java Persistence API, an ORM solution) and storing stuff in files, can you clarify?

Comment: I mean using JPA store those weather data into disk, not in database, but in file system. Is it clearer?

Comment: JPA is all about providing an OO view on relational data, so IMO your question is wrong, you don't use JPA to manage data in diskfiles.

Comment: :D.
Put it simply, how to store those data into diskfiles? So, we can retrieve them through web. the requirement of retrieving is "provide a dashboard view of current weather data in comparison to
climatology data. They have requested the current data to be in KML as well as the historical data. Ensure your system produces files that can be visualized using Google Earth."

Exactly, I am looking for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at the data, and the [description of what they contain](http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/igra/readme.txt), I don't think it's practical to keep those data in disk files if you want to extract information from them.  You'd probably be better off to design a couple of simple database tables in which to store these data, and query this database to get the data for your calculations, maybe with JPA.

A library that may help you to parse the data files is [JFileHelpers](http://jfilehelpers.com/index_en.php), it makes working with fixed-width and delimited files a lot easier.

Hope this helps to get you started.